# How to get value of dynamically created textbox web control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My aspx page contains list of products along with dynamically generated textboxes and one order button with each product.

Textboxes and buttons are generated at runtime with ids like txt110234,txt110235...so on for textboxes and btn110234,btn110235...so on for buttons.

Each time user have to enter quantity in the textbox and press order button associated with any product to place any order.

Every thing is working fine but now i want to do it using ajax,so i need to get the value entered by user in text box.I want to do something like this-

```
   var quan = document.getElementById('<%= txt' + id + '.ClientID%>').value;
```

But its giving me the following error.

> **Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal Source Error:**

How can i get the value of textbox?Any suggestion will be appreciated..

Comment: That **posted** code is JavaScript and that's why (C# ) it complaints. You have to use FindControl(id) to get the reference of control.

Comment: You probably have your javascript in a literal. You could directly place it on the page.

Comment: but i want to do it using javascript.is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got is because you can't involve javascript inside the "<%= .. %>" block. Also this doesn't look possible since the "<%= .. %>" expression is evaluated in server before the page is rendered, but your "id" is a client side variable.

You can set the script in server side like that:

client side code:

```
function foo(ctlID)
{
   var quan = document.getElementById(ctlID).value;
}
```

server side code:

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "SomeID";
Form.Controls.Add(txt);
Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "someID";
btn.OnClientClick = "foo('" + txt.ClientID + "')";
```

Comment: Thanks..Its really a nice solution..but i want textbox client id whereas it will return button's client id

Comment: yes,its giving me the id..but when m using in javascript code,its giving me null..

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add '' to the client id. Fixed it now.

Comment: I have added prefix 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_' before the id.my control is inside content place holder so its id looks like
    //'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt110234'.now its working.thanks for ur suggestion guys.

Comment: You don't have to do this manually and it is not safe. If you set the `OnClientClick` property after all controls are in their containers then you'll get the right id. Also, if you can ensure that you won't assign the same id for more than one control in the whole page, then you can use static id which means that ClientID is exactly like ID. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: I am lil confuse.Whats the risk in using this prefix?

Comment: The risk is that you discovered the string "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" by debugging. Are you sure it will always be like that? Do you know what will cause it to change? When something will cause it to change, how would you know this think happened?

Comment: Thanks..That was a stupid question.But how can i do this now.I am using .net2.0,so that there is no property like 'clientIDMode' i think.

Comment: If you're using .NET 2.0 you must stick to ClientID, but make sure you use it after all controls are in place and have id

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:
One way of doing this is to use jQuery css selector. You can assign a particular cssclass to all your input textbox and retrieve all of them via jQuery selector.

For example, on generating textboxes dynamically, you can assign them CssClass =".productQuantity"

and then later use jQuery selector something like $('.productQuantity')

I personally prefer this approach If I would like to traverse to multiple elements. This saves me from dealing with Ids etc.